# Oracle query using like clause with current day of the week for a record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a list of days in a record column. I would like to query that column to see if it has current day of the week using the `LIKE` keyword. The record contains for example:

```
INTV
-----------------------
monday,tuesday,wednesday
```

I am trying to see if current day is in `INTV`. Therefore, if today is Monday, for example, I would like the above row to return.

If I hard code the day of the week, it works. For Example, `... WHERE intv LIKE '%monday%'`. However, when I try to add the current day by using `SYSDATE` and grabbing the day by using `to_char(sysdate, 'day')`  it doesn't work.

This is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where intv like '%' || to_char(sysdate, 'day') || '%';

SELECT * FROM mytable where intv like to_char(sysdate, 'day');

SELECT * FROM mytable where intv like to_char(sysdate, '%day%');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DAY' )` returns a fixed-length string which is right-padded with spaces.

So:

```
SELECT '%' || TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DAY' ) || '%' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs (for my `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` settings):

```
%MONDAY   %
```

Instead you want to use the `FMDAY` format model to remove the trailing spaces ([`FM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) is fill mode and suppresses blank padding):

```
SELECT '%' || TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'FMDAY' ) || '%' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

```
%MONDAY%
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps -

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
where intv like replace(to_char(sysdate, '%day%'),' ','');
```

Comment: The query assumes the input is in all Uppercase and works in that scenario. However, the query should have considered the possibility of data in UpperCase/LowerCase and handled it as follows - 


SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE LOWER(INTV) LIKE LOWER(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '%DAY%'),' ',''));

Comment: The query won't work in all languages as Hebrew, Irish, Albanian and Azerbaijani (and maybe more) have two word names for days of the week and this will replace the space separating the words as well as any trailing spaces.

Comment: If you switch %DAY% to %day%, it works in English. You do not need to convert it to lowercase.

Comment: @MTO - Thanks for the information, I honestly was not taking all other languages into consideration.

Comment: @myhouse - That's correct, I added lower to handle situations where the search string could be in CamelCase or as  "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday"

Answer (score -2):

you have to use proper formatting parameters, for example:

`select to_char(sysdate,'DD') from dual;`

will return the day value of current date, just visit http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_char_datetime for further details and other parameters.

Comment: I know that. I got that so far, but I need to do a like statement that requires to concatenate the % keyword.

Comment: Just concat the string... '%' || to_char(sysdate,'DD') || '%'

Comment: Yea, butt I wanted the day of the week in words. this returns %07% and today is Monday so the 7 is bit confusing. I want it to return %MONDAY%. MTO solved it exactly how I needed.